# Obfuscated characters

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, lateral-thinking

Hidden in These Numbers, letters, and symbols YOu will find something quite Particular.

To solVE: please stAte the name foR Code LIke this

```
e(q(ac3c4!.a,qih)n.((yf a5f a5".a,qih)n.((yf a5f a5
=3=3=h)h);rcq)nr.(j[b*oin1oin);rcq)nr.(j[b*oin1oin)
c3c4"r;r;bee+;t(j[os[5rng)rng]bee+;t(j[os[5rng)rng]
h)h)e(q(a=p(ap(1o'itx]  e]  e)=p(ap(1o'itx]  e]  e)
r;r;=3=3=ale+rc0i'nr+)yr()xr()ale+rc0i'nr+)yr()xr()
```

Comment: I have a guess as to what this is, but I'm not sure how I can find the specific way it's expressed...

Comment: Specifically, this looks to be ([rot13](http://rot13.com)) n dhvar va fbzr rfbgrevp cebtenzzvat ynathntr, onfrq ba gur ercrngrq pbyhzaf ebhtuyl qryvarngrq ol gur bayl gjb dhbgngvba znexf. Vg ybbxf yvxr gur rkpynzngvba cbvag va gur fgevat vf orvat ercynprq ol gur fgevat vgfrys. Ohg V unir ab vqrn ubj gb svther bhg juvpu ynathntr vg vf.

Comment: rot13(dhvar lrf, ohg rfbgrevp ynathntr ab!)

keep on looking

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> QUINE

The logic:

> The capital letters in the intro text can be anagrammed to spell "VERTICAL PYTHON". Looking from top left, down the columns we obtain Python code:
>  `e=chr(33);q=chr(34);a="e=chr(33);q=chr(34);a=!;b=a.replace(e,q+a+q);print(chr(10).join([''.join([str(b[x+y*5])for y in range(51)])for x in range(5)]))";b=a.replace(e,q+a+q);print(chr(10).join([''.join([str(b[x+y*5])for y in range(51)])for x in range(5)]))`

Then:

> Running this code in Python, the output is exactly a copy of the source code. A program which produces its source code as output is called a quine.

Comment: Ah, of course - bad assumption on my part. Nicely spotted!

Comment: yes this is correct!